# Magento 2 : Only show products that is uploaded by admin user

Tags: magento2, admin-user

I have created an admin user from admin panel and assign a role to it in which this user only add and see products, but i want it to only show the product that he uploads not others product.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot differentiate the product once it got added them to repository by anyway either through import or manual creation.

Either you can do in this way by adding new attribute, so that all the admin users will have their own value of that attribute and now you can filter the product by using that attribute.